# mod_rewrite / redirection with ? in a query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm diving into the uses of htaccess/mod rewrite for the first time and I'm having a little bit of trouble with a redirect/mask.

I have a test directory in my root folder called `modrw`, in that folder is a `index.php` file with a nice and simple:

```
<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>
```

In the browser if I type `www.domain.com/modrw/{word}/` then the word is echoed on the page, which is what I want.

If I type `www.domain.com/modrw/name={word}` then I am redirected to `www.domain.com/modrw/{word}/` and the word is also echoed as I intended.

However, if I direct the browser to the URL `www.domain.com/modrw/?name={word}/` the word is echoed but I am not redirected to `www.domain.com/modrw/{word}/` like I hoped.

How is the `?` causing troubles? In the RewriteRule code below the `?` is included, I've tried it a couple different ways but can't get it working.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^modrw/?name=([^/\.]+)/?$ http://www.domain.com/modrw/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^modrw/([^/\.]+)/?$ modrw/?name=$1
```

What is causing the problem, is there a specific way to include the `?`, does it not pick this up at all? Am I taking completely the wrong approach?

I've also tried using `Options +FollowSymlinks` but I'm not entirely sure what this does nor if it's needed at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that RewriteRuleonly matches REQUEST_URI. To match query string you must use RewriteCond with variable %{QUERY_STRING}. For ex. in your case:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^modrw /modrw/%1? [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you! However, do I need to replace my current RerwiteRule or add this in addition, I tried adding this but by using both I get a redirect loop, and if I replace your code with mine, the redirection works for it with both a `?` and without, but I get 404'd

Comment: Do you need to support both of these URIs: 1) `www.domain.com/modrw/name={word}` and 2) `www.domain.com/modrw?name={word}`? If yes then pls also post your access.log and error.log relevant output here.

Comment: After a bit of thinking, I've decided the way I had gotten it working is actually good enough, links that are being masked/redirected are all links generated from my site, so unless someone manually types in a query into their browser I won't have any problems. Since they'll just get 404'd if the query doesn't match. `modrw/name={word}` redirects fine to `modrw/{word}/` and if {word} doesn't fetch results with a mysql query an error messages is displayed anyway. I don't know why I didn't think about it before! But thank you for your snippet, it will definitely come in handy soon, I'm sure! :)